# Block cross-domain iframe console logging

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, block, console.log

I'm making a page that has multiple iFrames that show reports. The reports generate a ton of console output which contributes to the page taking up more memory.

I tried to do the workaround with

```
console.log = function() {}
```

As well as a couple others I found, but none of them work. Majority of the errors are "Failed to load resource" and failed GET requests. I'm wondering if there's a way to maybe filter just those out.

Again the issue is that all the iFrames are cross domain and I have 0 access to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Failed requests and other browser errors are logged by the browser internally, not through `console.log`. There is no way for your page to filter them out. If you don't want to see them, don't look at the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
    iframeWindow.console.log = function() { /* nop */ };
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/gskf2dxx/12/) works on Mozilla,Chrome

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. As duskwuff said it's most likely just a browser error that I can't control :(